# COnverting Julian date in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, db2, gregorian-calendar, julian-date

I have a question. I am creating a report where the query pulls the `Julian Date` in iSeries DB2 for AS400.

How can I convert it to `Gregorian Date` in `SSRS`. I tried to modify my SQL query but was unsuccessful. So decided to convert it in SSRS.

Let's say I get a number `116193`. How do I convert it to `July 11 2016`. 
(Eg: 116193+1900000=2016193. 2016 year and 193rd day).

I can make a lot of if statements but I want something easier.

Answer (score 0):

Given: 116193 = Jul 11 2016

```
with YourTable as (
    select 116193 as juldate
    )

select
   juldate, adjdate, thedate
from YourTable t
cross apply (select t.Juldate+1899999 adjdate) a1
cross apply (
      select dateadd(day,adjdate % 1000,dateadd(year,(adjdate/1000)-1900,0)) thedate
    ) a2

+---------+---------+---------------------+
| juldate | adjdate |       thedate       |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  116193 | 2016192 | 11.07.2016 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

The first cross apply just supplies an alias that can be used in the second apply. it can be done without either if preferred.

```
select 
dateadd(day,(t.Juldate+1899999) % 1000,dateadd(year,((t.Juldate+1899999)/1000)-1900,0)) thedate
from YourTable t
```

btw: because a year starts with Jan 1, the date arithmetic requires 1 day less than 193 i.e. if you add 193 days to Jan 1 you would get 12th July.

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL

```
DECLARE @JulianDate INT = 116193

SELECT DATEADD(DD, CAST(Right(@JulianDate + 1900000, 3) AS INT) - 1, CAST(LEFT(@JulianDate + 1900000, 4) AS DATE))
```

IN SSRS,

```
= DateAdd("d",CInt(Right(Fields!Julian.Value + 1900000, 3)) - 1 , CDate("1/1/"& Left(Fields!Julian.Value + 1900000, 4)))
```